# Get current state of Java interface from Jar file

Tags: java, jar

This may be a weird request, but I'm going to ask it.

I have a open-source software, written in Java.I modified it for a project.

The software lets me place some elements on its interface and link the elements together.I modified the code to add some extra elements.
After compilation the software is generated in a executable .jar file.

The software only provides the option to sync with a certain server but I do not have access to that server.
Also,the software does not provide any save option to save the current state of the interface.

My question is : Is there a way to find and/or save the current state of the interface? Like an option to save current state in a temporary folder?

I tried to implement my own save option method but the software is huge, with many classes.all the classes are dedicated for the server sync.Hence, it is  a difficult problem to solve.

Thank you!

Comment: First things first...what do you mean by "interface"?  Is this a **graphical user interface**?  If so, does it use Java's Swing library? AWT? Some web technology?

Comment: Given that you have the sources and can modify them, yes, it's possible to do whatever you want. What do you expect from us exactly?